# How to overwrite / intercept console.log and output original log to console

Tags: javascript, arguments, console.log

I'm trying to intercept console.log and write it to an array to access the log programatically. This should be cross browser compliant.

```
window["log"]=[];
var logger = console.log;
console.log = function() {
  window["log"].push({arguments});
  // neither seems to output as original
  logger( arguments );
  logger.call ( arguments );
  logger.call ( console, arguments );
  logger.apply ( arguments );
}
```

My problem is that `logger( arguments)` always writes an array to console and not the original message. How can I make console output the original message with original line numbers and file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
logger.apply(console, arguments);
```

...which calls the original function with `this` set to `console` and with `arguments` spread out as discrete arguments.

---

Side note: If you want to be broadly-compatible, you'll need to replace the ES2015+ code here:

```
window["log"].push({arguments});
```

with ES5-compatible code:

```
window["log"].push({arguments: arguments});
```